# Replace all contents of a googlesheet using R googlesheets package?

Tags: r, r-googlesheets

Just discovered the [googlesheets](https://github.com/jennybc/googlesheets) package and find it very helpful thus far. I would now like to be able to replace all or a subset of the contents in an existing sheet.

Example:

```
> library(googlesheets) 
> set.seed(10)
> test1 <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10),nrow = 5))
> test1
       X1         X2
1  0.01874617  0.3897943
2 -0.18425254 -1.2080762
3 -1.37133055 -0.3636760
4 -0.59916772 -1.6266727
5  0.29454513 -0.2564784

> gs_new("foo_sheet", input = test1, trim = TRUE)
```

This creates a new sheet as expected. Let's say that we then need to update the sheet (this data is used for a shinyapps.io hosted shiny app, and I would prefer to not have to redeploy the app in order to change sheet references).

```
> test1$X2 <- NULL
> test1
       X1
1  0.01874617
2 -0.18425254
3 -1.37133055
4 -0.59916772
5  0.29454513
```

I tried to simply overwrite with `gs_new()` but run into the following warning message:

```
> gs_new("foo_sheet", input = test1, trim = TRUE)  

Warning message:
At least one sheet matching "foo_sheet" already exists, so you may
need to identify by key, not title, in future.
```

This results in a new sheet `foo_sheet` being created with a new `key`, but does not replace the existing sheet and will therefore produce a `key` error if we try to register the updated sheet with

```
gs_title("foo_sheet")

Error in gs_lookup(., "sheet_title", verbose) : 
"foo_sheet" matches sheet_title for multiple sheets returned by gs_ls() (which should reflect user's Google Sheets home screen). Suggest you identify this sheet by unique key instead.
```

This means that if we later try to access the new sheet `foo_sheet` with `gs_read("foo_sheet")`, the API will return the original sheet, rather than the new one.

```
> df <- gs_read("foo_sheet")
> df
       X1         X2
1  0.01874617  0.3897943
2 -0.18425254 -1.2080762
3 -1.37133055 -0.3636760
4 -0.59916772 -1.6266727
5  0.29454513 -0.2564784
```

It is my understanding that one possible solution could be to first delete the sheet with `gs_delete("test1")` and then create a new one. Alternatively one could perhaps empty cells with `gs_edit_cells()`, but was hoping for some form of overwrite function.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that the edit cells function is a good workaround:

```
gs_edit_cells(ss = "foo_sheet", ws = "worksheet name", input = test1, anchor = "A1" trim = TRUE, col_names = TRUE)
```

By anchoring the data to the upper left corner, you can effectively overwrite all other data. The trim function will eliminate all cells that are not to be updated.

Comment: There is an ongoing problem in `gs_edit_cells`. It hangs several times.